# python web socket handshake not working

Tags: python

I am trying to do a handshake but i keep getting the error:
*failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value*

What am i doing wrong?

server:

```
import socket
import re
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1
GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
websocket_answer = (
    'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
    'Upgrade: websocket',
    'Connection: Upgrade',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n',
)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host='10.10.10.12'
port=8999
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
client_list = []

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    if(s not in client_list):
        client_list.append(s)
        key = (re.search('Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', data.decode('utf-8'))
            .groups()[0]
            .strip())
        print('key' + key)
        response_key = b64encode(sha1((key + GUID).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        response = '\r\n'.join(websocket_answer).format(key=response_key)
        print('_________________RESPONSE________________')
        print(response.encode('ascii'))
        conn.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
    else:
        print(str(data))
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = new WebSocket('ws://10.10.10.12:8999');
        s.onmessage = function(t){console.log(t)};
        s.onopen = function(){
          s.send('hello from client');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html

Comment: Im 45% sure the response_key is incorrect. but the documentation says, "concatenate the key and GUID, hash it with sha1, and base64 encode it". but that is what i have done https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers . It could also be an encoding problem??

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
import socket
import re
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1
GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
websocket_answer = (
    'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
    'Upgrade: websocket',
    'Connection: Upgrade',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n',
)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host='10.10.10.12'
port=8999
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
#print('Connected by', addr)
client_list = []

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    if(s not in client_list):
        client_list.append(s)
        key = (re.search('Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', data.decode('utf-8'))
            .groups()[0]
            .strip())
        #print('key' + key)
        sha1f = sha1()
        sha1f.update(key.encode('utf-8') + GUID.encode('utf-8'))
        response_key = b64encode(sha1f.digest()).decode('utf-8')
        response = '\r\n'.join(websocket_answer).format(key=response_key)
        #print('_________________RESPONSE________________')
        #print(response)
        conn.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
    else:
          pass
        #print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    print(str(data).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
```